# Sort array with special character

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How sort values to names will first alphabetic and "@" names after them?

So sort the following:

```
 @3
 zpo
 ahb
 @1
 @7
 bes
 kk
```

Like this:

```
 ahb
 bes
 kk
 zpo
 @1
 @3
 @7
```

If I use `asort()`, "@" names are first, they must be last.

Comment: Does this only apply to the `@` symbol or do you want any "special" characters to be sorted at the bottom?

Comment: You'll probably need to use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to do this.

Comment: I did this, this not working... All new values are in turn placed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fun way:

```
 asort($array); 
 $array = (array_diff($array, $temp = preg_grep('/^@/', $array)) + $temp);
```

1. find all the items beginning with `@` using `preg_grep()`
2. find the difference, meaning the items not starting with `@` using `array_diff()`
3. add 2 + 1

If you want all special characters you can try with `/^[^\w\d]/` or specific ones like `/^[@%#]/` etc.

Comment: Very creative and short, nice!

Comment: It probably not working for my array, because array looks like this: Array([0] => Array(['login'] => 'aaa') [1] => Array(['login'] => '@2') [2] => Array(['login'] => '@3')). Username is in indoor array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `usort`

```
usort($a,function($a,$b) {
    //if the left string starts with an '@' and
    //and the right string doesn't start with an '@',
    //then the left string is considered greater than the right, return 1        
    if($a[0] == '@' && $b[0] != '@') {
        return 1; 
    }    

    //see above comment        
    if($b[0] == '@' && $a[0] != '@') {
        return -1;
    }

    //if both strings start with an '@'
    //or both strings do not start with an '@'
    //do a regular comparison
    return strcmp($a,$b);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a regular sort, but set aside the values starting with @, put them in a separate array and merge those two (the second array will be appended to the first). Something like this:

```
<?php
$arr = ['@3', 'zpo', 'ahb', '@1', '@7', 'bes', 'kk'];

asort($arr); // Regular sorting

$arr2 = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (0 === strpos($value, '@')) {
        $arr2[] = $value; // Add the value to the secondary array
        unset($arr[$key]); // Remove the key from the primary array
    }
}

array_merge($arr, $arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
$arr = array(
 '@3',
 'zpo',
 'ahb',
 '@1',
 '@7',
 'bes',
 'kk',
);
function sorting($array){
    asort($array);
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        if(strstr($v,'@')){
            unset($array[$k]);
            array_push($array,$v);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
var_dump(sorting($arr));
```